# How to set the tab as disabled/enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a task to disable and enable tabs on the click of the checkbox.But in my first tab I have two filds name and age. The second tab is enabled only after the completion of the validation of first tab.I can show the tab by selecting the check box but it should not enabled.How can I do this?
My Html code is

```
 <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-0">Tab1</a> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-0"> <b>Name</b>

            <input type="text" id="name" />
            <br/> <b>Age</b>
            <input type="text" id="age" />
            <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tabs-0" value="0" checked>tabs-1
    <input type="checkbox" name="tabs-1" value="1" disabled>tabs-2
    <input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2" disabled>tabs-3
    <input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3" disabled>tabs-4

            <input type="submit" value="next" class="submit" />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-1"> <b>city</b>

            <input type="text" id="name" />
            <br/> <b>state</b>

            <input type="text" id="age" />
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="next" class="submit" />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Tab3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Tab4</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
        "selected": 0,
            "disabled": [1, 2, 3]
    });

    $('.submit').click(function () {
        if($('#name').val()=='')
        {
            alert("empty");
        }
        else
        {
        var nexttab = parseInt($(this).parent().next().attr('id').match(/\d+/g), 10);
        $('#tabs').tabs("enable", nexttab).tabs("select", nexttab);
        $('input[name="tabs-'+nexttab+'"]').removeAttr('disabled').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });


    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
            $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val()-1);
        } else {
            $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
            var tab = $(this);
            $(":checked").each(function (index) {
                $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val());
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/63/)

Comment: Not able to get you properly! What is your main issue? Is the check-box or tabs not working??

Comment: Actually I want to make the second,third and forth tab visible but not enabled while clicking checkbox of first tab.The tab must enabled only after the pressing of the first tab button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding. Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-1" value="1" checked>tabs-2
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2" checked>tabs-3
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3" checked>tabs-4
```

Instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-1" value="1" disabled>tabs-2
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2" disabled>tabs-3
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3" disabled>tabs-4
```

Remove CSS

```
.ui-state-disabled {
 display: none;
 }
```

JS Changes

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 0            
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/60/)

Comment: @AmitAgrawal-Actually I want to make the second,third and forth tab visible but not enabled while clicking checkbox of first tab.The tab must enabled only after the pressing of the first tab's next button

Comment: Wait i am trying to implement it

Comment: @amitagrawal- I need all checkbox as selected and also i have to select it.But while selecting the second tab is shown but its not selected.It must be in disabled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28657/discussion-between-agent1-and-amit-agrawal)